# OpenCv Image From RGB Array

Tags: opencv, imagemagick, rgb

I have an array of RGB values from ImageMagick and I would like to create an IplImage structure in opencv. I was wondering how can I set the contents of the IplImage to be the rgb array values without writing the ImageMagick image to the hdd and then rereading it.

Answer (score 1):

so you want to convert an ImageMagick Image object to an IplImage. It is just a matter of writing it to a buffer and then create an IplImage out of that buffer. The code from here (http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=18183):

```
void Magick2Ipl(Image magicImage, IplImage* cvImage)
{
   int width= magicImage.size().width();
   int height = magicImage.size().height();

   byte* blob= new byte[cvImage->imageSize];
   magicImage.write(0,0, width, height, "BGRA", MagickCore::CharPixel, blob);
   memcpy(cvImage->imageData, blob, cvImage->imageSize);
   delete [] blob;
}
```

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

- You can do it by this way also,

  ```
  Image image("Image_Path");   

  int width = image.size().width();
  int height = image.size().height();

  IplImage* mat = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
  image.write(0, 0, width, height, "BGR", Magick::CharPixel, (char*)mat->imageData);

  cvShowImage("image", mat);
  ```